# Is it possible for python to read a column and assign every row in that column a separate variable?

Tags: python, csv

I don't have any code right now, but if possible, where would i start after inputting my csv file?

Maybe there's an easier way of doing this, but once i can assign each cell its own variable i'd like to use pyad to validate if the variable is disabled or enabled in python against active directory

Comment: I think it would be easier to store each row in a dictionary entry.

Comment: yes or store the rows in a list

Answer (score 0):

Decided to turn my comment into an answer.

You need to "assign every row in that column a separate variable", hence I assume you want every cell in that column to be its own separate variable

I am not exactly sure how you use `pyad`, but logically if you need to access each row by name, I would recommend using a Python [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) to accomplish this task.

Before beginning to read through your CSV file, create an empty dictionary; as you read through your column, create new entries in the dictionary with key the variable name you wanted, and value the value of the cell. You can then access the values regularly but instead of `variable_name` you need to use `dict_name["variable_name"]`.

Comment: what if the amount of row's change?

Comment: Then you can just add a new entry in the dictionary, or just generate the key names dynamically, but then I think it would be more suitable to use a regular list.